# Sql Server - How to get last id inserted into table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the last id inserted into a table.
I was using

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('TABLE')
```

But the problem is that it doesn't return the last inserted id, it returns the max inserted id.

For example, if i do:

```
INSERT INTO 'TABLA' (ID) VALUES (100)

SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('TABLE') returns 100
```

but then if i do

```
INSERT INTO 'TABLA' (ID) VALUES (50)

SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('TABLE') returns 100
```

and I want to get 50

I need the ID of a specific table, and I generate the id dinamically, so it's not an identity
How can i do it?

Comment: `IDENT_CURRENT` expects an automatically incrementing column. If you are able to manually insert IDs, you either are not using an auto-increment number, or your auto-increment has been turned off (using `SET IDENTITY_INSERT`).

Comment: Yes, I need to SET IDENTITY_INSERT to Off because I need to be able to generate the id before inserting it.

Comment: -That's always a bad idea. Automatically generated IDs should be exactly that. If you need to manually generate ID numbers, it will lead to administrative head aches in the long run. In any case, it will mean you simply cannot rely on IDENT_CURRENT for retrieving the last inserted ID. I would suggest reviewing the business process that requires you to override auto-identity. Otherwise go with Phil Sandlers's solution.

Answer (score 5):

From your code, it looks like ID is not an identity (auto-increment) column, so IDENT_CURRENT isn't going to do what you are expecting.

If you want to find the last row inserted, you will need a datetime column that represents the insert time, and then you can do something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [ID] FROM TABLEA ORDER BY [InsertedDate] DESC
```

Edited: a few additional notes:

- Your InsertedDate column should have a default set to GetDate() unless your application, stored procs or whatever you use to perform inserts will be responsible for setting the value
- The reason I said your ID is not an identity/auto-increment is because you are inserting a value into it.  This is only possible if you turn identity insert off.

Comment: Yes, I'm turning off the identity insert, because I need to generate the id before sending the insert. It's a good idea, but I have restrictions, and I cannot save the inserted date

Comment: If nothing in the table represents the date or order of insert, you can't reliably find the first or last row inserted, plain and simple.

Comment: @mar_sanbas if you are generating the value from the client, why is it an identity column at all? And if you are passing the value, why do you need to look it up? Don't you already know it, because you just passed it?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

will return the last value inserted in current session. 
**Edit**
Then what you are doing is the best way to go just make sure that the ID Column is an IDENTITY Column, IDENT_CURRENT('Table_name'), @@IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY() returns last value generated by the Identity column. 

 If the ID column is not an Identity Column, all of these functions will return NULL.

Comment: I need the last inserted id of a specific table

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not keep track of the last value inserted into an `IDENTITY` column, particularly when you use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON;`. But if you are manually specifying the value you are inserting, you don't need SQL Server to tell you what it is. You already know what it is, because you just specified it explicitly in the `INSERT` statement.

If you can't get your code to keep track of the value it ***just inserted***, and can't change the table to have a DateInserted column with a default of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (which would allow you to see which row was inserted last), perhaps you could add a trigger to the table that logs all inserts.